# Access VBA code for copying information from a combobox and pasting into a textbox on a continuous form

Tags: vba, ms-access, combobox

Really need help with this, I have a continuous form with a combo box to choose data, each row has a different criteria and you can choose only certain items per row in the combo box drop down. (As an example I have four rows one is a cap, one is a bottle, one is a label and the last is oil to go in the bottle.)

What I need is when I have chosen something in the combo box drop down I want it to paste into a text box and stay there until another choice on the same row is made...... Currently I can make the information appear in the textbox but then when I move to another row and choose anothe item it over writes anything I have already chosen.

So an example would be I have chosen product 1, it has cap 1, bottle 1, label 1 and oil 1. In the drop down combo box I can choose only bottles to replace bottles caps to replace caps and so on. I want to choose bottle 2 in the combo box on the bottle line (Which changes all the combo boxes) I now want to save that choice in the text box on the bottle row only, then when I choose Label 2 on the label row even though it changes all the combo boxes I don't want it to overwrite the text box for the bottle row. (I'm assuming a criteria that will only change the row of the combo box you are clicking on or something like that)

hope this makes sense to every body (P.S. I don't know how to get a screen shot in here so have tried to explain to the best of my ability)

Many thanks

Justin

Comment: So is what you want to do is have the updates from the combobox selections append to a textbox? After you change a combobox you are seeing the other combo boxes change, even though you don't expect them too? Just to verify: are each of your combo boxes populated from a different table in the database?

Comment: Hi @Nick Thanks for your response. Yeah, currently the combo boxes are changing on every selection, so I put the textboxes to capture the row data so when you change a bottle it doesn't effect the label row and when you select a cap it doesn't effect the bottle row. I tried to build this as a work around as the combo boxes are changing when I don't want them too. All data comes initially comes from one table and the combo boxes are all from another table. They are defined by criteria to determine whether a bottle is a bottle etc.

Comment: Are all of your four fields in the same table? For example do you have tblProductProperties with four fields in it called Label, Cap, Bottle, and Oil?

Comment: Yeah, they are all in the same table and defined by a unique field, i have made the row source on the combo boxes a query in which I match against the base data (i.e. I have the base data table, in there is a field (bottle, Cap, Label, Oil) and match this in the row source of the combo box to the list data that I am selecting from which has a field (bottle, Cap, Label, Oil) So there might be 10 bottles/caps/labels/oils and you can use the combo box to select them. (To stop users replacing a cap with a bottle)

Comment: okay, so the short answer is that you need to break those out into different tables. I'll write a more detailed answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have to bind the textbox to a field in the record.

As long as the textbox is unbound, it doesn't know about a record and will display the same for all records.

Comment: Hi @Gustav, thanks for the quick response. How exactly would you do this? Do you mean binding the combo box or binding the text box to the combo box? Still relatively new to this

Comment: Set its ControlSource to a (new) field of the table.

Answer (score 0):

I'm making the assumption that you want to be able to map some product to 4 different types of caps, bottles, labels, and oil:

It seems that your problem is in your data table design, not in your comboboxes. You shouldn't need the text field at all. The problem is that your comboboxes are all based on the same table. When you select Bottle2 from one of them, it matches the rest of the comboboxes to that row. So all the others will get Label2, Cap2, etc. because they are in the same row of the table.

Make a products table call it tblProducts. The fields ID (autonumber), product_name, label_FK, cap_FK, Bottle_FK, and oil_FK should be in it. Those FK stand for Foreign key and should be a number type. The product name can be text.

Create the tblLabel, tblCap, etc. with an ID, and a description.

In your relationships you need to map the tblLable.ID to the tblProducts.Label_FK field. Do this for all 4 type. Then you can re-create the form based on the products table. Whatever the form gives you for the way to control the label_FK, cap_FK, etc. fields you can convert it to a combobox by right click -> change to...

Finally, you may need to update the number of columns of the comboboxes in order to see the description also.

EDIT: More lasting information -
Doing some solid research on data table design will pay huge dividends in design time. Starting with the [Database Design Basics](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Database-design-basics-EB2159CF-1E30-401A-8084-BD4F9C9CA1F5) page from Microsoft will help as a decent 30 minute intro and should help clear some things up for you.

Comment: Thanks nick, will try that